# Iterating over lists stored in data.frame in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, loops

I think this is a beginner question, but I don't appear to have the right vocabulary for an effective Google search.

I have a data.frame, `final`, which contains a list of `clusters`, each of which is a list of strings.

I would like to iterate over the list of strings in each cluster: a for loop within a for loop.

```
for (j in final$clusters){
    for (i in final$clusters$`j`){
        print final$clusters$`j`[i]
    }
}
```

`j` corresponds to the lists in `clusters`, and `i` corresponds to the items in `clusters[j]`

I was trying to do this by using the length of each cluster, which I thought would be something like `length(final$clusters[1])`, but that gives 1, not the length of list.

Also, `final$clusters[1]` gives $'1', and on the next line, all the strings in cluster 1.

Thanks.

EDIT: output of `dput(str(final))`, as requested:

```
List of 2
 $ clusters     :List of 1629
  ..$ 1   :
  ..$ 2   : 
  ..$ 3   : 
  ..$ 4   : 
  ..$ 5   : 
  ..$ 6   : 
  ..$ 7   : 
  ..$ 8   : 
  ..$ 9   : 
  ..$ 10  : 
  .. [list output truncated]
 $ cluster_stats: num [1:1629, 1:6] 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:1629] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "min" "qu1" "median" "mean" ...
NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you confuse a `list` and a `data.frame`. I guess that your final is object is a list.

To iterate over the list You can use `rapply`. It is a recursive version of lapply.

For example:

```
## I create some reproducible example

cluster1 <- list(a='a',b='b')
cluster2 <- list(c='aaa',d='bbb')
clusters <- list(cluster1,cluster2)
final <- list(clusters)
```

So using `rapply`

```
rapply(final,f=print)
[1] "a"
[1] "b"
[1] "aaa"
[1] "bbb"
    a     b     c     d 
  "a"   "b" "aaa" "bbb"
```

**Update** after edit by OP

Using `lapply`, I loop through the name of the list. For each name, I get the element list using `[[` ( you can use `[` if you wand to get names and heder for files), then I write the file using `write.table`. Here I use the name of the element in the list to create the file name. in your case you will have file name as number.(1.txt,...)

```
    lapply(names(final$clusters),
                      function(x)
                             write.table(x=final$clusters[[x]],
                                         file=paste(x,'.txt',sep='')))
```

Comment: So `rapply` is working as you stated, to print out the list of lists (thanks for the clarification).  However, I'd like to print out only one of the lists at a time (actually, I was hoping to use `sink` to print each of `clusters` to a different file), but I cannot get `print` to work, using @pipo98 's help and yours:  `for (j in final$clusters){ rapply(final$clusters[j], f = print) }` returns many lines of `NULL`.

Comment: @dd3 no need to combine `rapply` with `for`. `Rapply` will go recusrivly through the list to get the leafs.. can you please dput the `dput(str(final))` and add it to your question...

Comment: the problem is I only want to do this for one of the sublists at a time.  In your example, I'd like to get only the output of `cluster1`, write that to a file, and then do the same for the other clusters, each one writing to a different file. I've added the output you requested to my question.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I think the primary problem here is that the way you iterate here is wrong.

I think that something like this would work better:

```
for (j in final$clusters){
    for (i in final$clusters[j]){
        print i
    }
}
```

here is the documentation
for loops: http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r#TOC-For-Loop
for subsetting: http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html

good luck

Comment: Thanks for catching this! However, it doesn't entirely solve my problem.  (I would upvote your answer, but I don't have the reputation to do that. sorry.)